# Please explain why this post is off-topic

Tags: discussion

[How do you handle a lead who is verbally abusive to you and makes misleading statements](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33323/how-do-you-handle-a-lead-who-is-verbally-abusive-to-you-and-makes-misleading-st)

A few of us worked very hard to get this question in a format that is within the guidelines of the Workplace.  It has now been put on-hold as off-topic. Could someone please explain how dealing with an abusive lead is not within the topics to be discussed on "the Workplace"?

Answer (score 5):

The question reads as:

1. I hate my boss
2. The options open to me don't appeal
3. What should I do?

I don't see a *practical answerable questions based on actual problems you face* in there. I see a complaint about the current situation and absolutely no indication of what would count as solving the problem, why approaching HR (a solution they brought up themselves) isn't ideal, or what the heck they are expecting in an answer.

Comment: How could we rephrase the question to take out the whining and point to the fact that someone in a position of authority is being verbally abusive to one of thier subordinates? Again, I feel this is a great topic to address in the Workplace. That's why I whittled down the original rage-fest to the short note you see today...

Comment: @MikeVanTrufflebutt, that depends on what the actual question is, and what problem it is trying to solve -- the current question doesn't address that, which is why I can't suggest a rephrasing, since that would be inventing content I can't see there.

Comment: @MikeVanTrufflebutt, you could leave comments to the asker with some clarifying questions. In these cases where the question isn't clear, we can oftentimes tease it out of them just by us asking the right questions. Hope this helps.

Comment: Of course, I can see an argument for the post being a lot better than it was originally. Maybe it just needs someone to drop this link in chat to get more members of the community involved...